# LIMIT and UNION ALL not returning the requested number of records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with multiple `type` values and I'm wanting to get a sample records from some of them.

My current query is as follows:

```
-- Pulling three sample records from each "type"
SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "A" LIMIT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "B" LIMIT 3
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "C" LIMIT 3
;
```

I expect this to return a total of 9 records; 3 from `type = "A"`, 3 from `type = "B"`, and 3 from `type = "C"`.

However, the result that I actually receive is 3 records from `type = "A"` *and nothing else*.
I know for a fact that the other `type` values exist because I can run the individual `SELECT` statements and they return results.

Why is MySQL only returning 3 records and how can I have it return the full 9 records that I want?

I've created a SQL Fiddle to illustrate the issue: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d911c/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use parentheses:

```
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "A" LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "B" LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "C" LIMIT 3);
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d911c/3)

This is documented in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/union.html):

> To apply ORDER BY or LIMIT to an individual SELECT, place the clause
>   inside the parentheses that enclose the SELECT:
>
> (SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10) UNION
>   (SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2 ORDER BY a LIMIT 10);

Comment: That must be a MySQL-ism.  I'm not used to enclosing entire SELECT statements in parentheses.  Without parentheses, what takes precedence?  The final LIMIT?  Or is it cumulative, i.e. each LIMIT applies to all SELECTS before it?

Comment: @Mr.Llama This seems to be a peculiarity of MySQL. If you use `TOP 3` in SQL Server you will get 3x3 = 9 rows returned. `LIMIT 3` is applied just once to the whole result set return by the `UNION ALL` operators. See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d911c/13)

Answer (score 2):

Put parentheses around the selects

```
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "A" LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "B" LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM example WHERE type = "C" LIMIT 3)
```

#### [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d911c/3)

Answer (score 0):

The limit is applied to all rows, not just each section. i.e. your setting a limit of 3 on all queries, not each section. So in order to apply a limit to each section you'd need to sub query it:

```
SELECT * FROM (select * from example WHERE type = "A" LIMIT 3) tbl1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (select * from example WHERE type = "B" LIMIT 3) tbl2
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM (select * from example WHERE type = "C" LIMIT 3) tbl3
;
```

That should give you the result you are looking for